# How do you turn back on the menu-bar permanently having installed the emacs-starter-kit?

Tags: emacs

I'm just trying to pick up emacs after 20 or so years away as it appears to be the best way to use Clojure and Overtone. Having installed the emacs-starter-kit I have lost the menubar which was proving very useful to reorient myself with the emacs commands. From searching I can see that C-x F10 restores it for a session, how do I turn it back on by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, emacs-starter-kit would not be so unwise as to make it difficult to turn menus back on.

Try putting this in your init file (`~/.emacs`), after whatever you have that loads the starter-kit:

```
 (menu-bar-mode 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, I ended up doing the same thing through `M-x customize-variable menu-bar-mode` as suggested in [an answer](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/issues/165) to the issue I posted on their Github page

Comment: Yes, that is even better (IMO).  The key is to make sure the code setting the variable is evaluated after the starter kit has done its thing.